# How do I get 3 <select> elements work together

Tags: angular, jhipster

I'm trying to get **3 select elements** working together as a filter in a html-file within a JHipster (4.14.0) project using angular front-end.

Screenshot:

[image]

***event-angjs.component.html***

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 btn-group flex-btn-group-container">
  <select [(ngModel)]="currentOperation" class="form-control" (change)="filter(currentOperation)">
    <option [ngValue]="null" disabled><span jhiTranslate="filterOperation"></span></option>
    <option *ngFor="let operationOption of operations;"    
            [ngValue]="operationOption.id"> 
      <span>{{operationOption.opName}}</span>
    </option>
 </select>
  <select class="form-control" id="filterProcesses">
    <option [ngValue]="null" disabled><span jhiTranslate="filterProcesses"></span></option>
    <option [ngValue]="processesOption.id"
            *ngFor="let processesOption of processes;">
      <span>{{processesOption.proRequestNumberPurpose}}</span>
    </option>
  </select>
  <select class="form-control" id="filterHotspots">
    <option [ngValue]="null" disabled><span jhiTranslate="filterHotspot"></span></option>
    <option [ngValue]="hotspotsOption.id" *ngFor="let hotspotsOption of hotspots;">
      <span>{{hotspotsOption.hotName}}</span>
    </option>
  </select>
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">clear</button>
</div>
```

The *filterProcess* and *filterHotspot* element shall get their option-list **depending** **on** the **selection** of *filterOperation* element.

I already got option-list filled by importing HotspotService and ProcessService to *event-angjs.component.ts*

Now I'm looking for a way to use the results of my modified */web/rest/HotspotResource.java* and */web/rest/ProcessResource.java* to filter the option-list of process and hotspot dropdown-element.

The Resource already give me correct results via

**swagger-api**

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

After digging deeper i'm getting stuck on the TypeScript part

***event-angjs.component.ts***

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  OnDestroy
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  ActivatedRoute,
  Router
} from '@angular/router';
import {
  Subscription
} from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import {
  JhiEventManager,
  JhiParseLinks,
  JhiAlertService
} from 'ng-jhipster';

import {
  EventAngjs
} from './event-angjs.model';
import {
  EventAngjsService
} from './event-angjs.service';
// für Dropdown Filter
import {
  OperationAngjs,
  OperationAngjsService
} from '../operation-angjs';
import {
  HotspotAngjs,
  HotspotAngjsService
} from '../hotspot-angjs';
import {
  ProcessesAngjs,
  ProcessesAngjsService
} from '../processes-angjs';

import {
  ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
  Principal
} from '../../shared';

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-event-angjs',
  templateUrl: './event-angjs.component.html'
})
export class EventAngjsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  currentAccount: any;
  events: EventAngjs[];
  // für Dropdown Filter
  operations: OperationAngjs[];
  processes: ProcessesAngjs[];
  hotspots: HotspotAngjs[];

  error: any;
  success: any;
  eventSubscriber: Subscription;
  currentSearch: string;
  currentOperation: string;
  routeData: any;
  links: any;
  totalItems: any;
  queryCount: any;
  itemsPerPage: any;
  page: any;
  predicate: any;
  previousPage: any;
  reverse: any;

  constructor(
    private eventService: EventAngjsService,
    // für Dropdown Filter
    private operationService: OperationAngjsService,
    private processesService: ProcessesAngjsService,
    private hotspotService: HotspotAngjsService,

    private parseLinks: JhiParseLinks,
    private jhiAlertService: JhiAlertService,
    private principal: Principal,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private eventManager: JhiEventManager
  ) {
    this.itemsPerPage = ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
    this.routeData = this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data) => {
      this.page = data.pagingParams.page;
      this.previousPage = data.pagingParams.page;
      this.reverse = data.pagingParams.ascending;
      this.predicate = data.pagingParams.predicate;
    });
    this.currentSearch = this.activatedRoute.snapshot && this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['search'] ?
      this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['search'] : '';
  }

  loadAll() {
    if (this.currentSearch) {
      this.eventService.search({
        page: this.page - 1,
        query: this.currentSearch,
        size: this.itemsPerPage,
        sort: this.sort()
      }).subscribe(
        (res: HttpResponse < EventAngjs[] > ) => this.onSuccess(res.body, res.headers),
        (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
      );
      return;
    }
    this.eventService.query({
      page: this.page - 1,
      size: this.itemsPerPage,
      sort: this.sort()
    }).subscribe(
      (res: HttpResponse < EventAngjs[] > ) => this.onSuccess(res.body, res.headers),
      (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
    );
  }
  loadPage(page: number) {
    if (page !== this.previousPage) {
      this.previousPage = page;
      this.transition();
    }
  }
  transition() {
    this.router.navigate(['/event-angjs'], {
      queryParams: {
        page: this.page,
        size: this.itemsPerPage,
        search: this.currentSearch,
        sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')
      }
    });
    this.loadAll();
  }

  clear() {
    this.page = 0;
    this.currentSearch = '';
    this.router.navigate(['/event-angjs', {
      page: this.page,
      sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')
    }]);
    this.loadAll();
  }
  search(query) {
    if (!query) {
      return this.clear();
    }
    this.page = 0;
    this.currentSearch = query;
    this.router.navigate(['/event-angjs', {
      search: this.currentSearch,
      page: this.page,
      sort: this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')
    }]);
    this.loadAll();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadAll();
    this.principal.identity().then((account) => {
      this.currentAccount = account;
    });
    this.registerChangeInEvents();
    // für Dropdown Filter
    // TODO: Anpassen für Parameterübergabe
    this.operationService.query()
      .subscribe((res: HttpResponse < OperationAngjs[] > ) => {
        this.operations = res.body;
      }, (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message));
    this.processesService.query()
      .subscribe((res: HttpResponse < ProcessesAngjs[] > ) => {
        this.processes = res.body;
      }, (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message));
    this.hotspotService.query()
      .subscribe((res: HttpResponse < HotspotAngjs[] > ) => {
        this.hotspots = res.body;
      }, (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message));
  }

  filter(id: number) {

    //PLACEHOLDER for ngModel currentOperation

    this.eventService.queryByOperation(id)
      .subscribe((res: HttpResponse < EventAngjs[] > ) => {
        this.events = res.body;
      }, (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message));
    this.processesService.query()
      .subscribe((res: HttpResponse < ProcessesAngjs[] > ) => {
        this.processes = res.body;
      }, (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message));
    this.hotspotService.query(id)
      .subscribe((res: HttpResponse < HotspotAngjs[] > ) => {
        this.hotspots = res.body;
      }, (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.eventManager.destroy(this.eventSubscriber);
  }

  trackId(index: number, item: EventAngjs) {
    return item.id;
  }

  // für Dropdown Filter
  trackOperationById(index: number, item: OperationAngjs) {
    return item.id;
  }
  trackProcessesById(index: number, item: ProcessesAngjs) {
    return item.id;
  }
  trackHotspotById(index: number, item: HotspotAngjs) {
    return item.id;
  }
  registerChangeInEvents() {
    this.eventSubscriber = this.eventManager.subscribe('eventListModification', (response) => this.loadAll());
  }

  sort() {
    const result = [this.predicate + ',' + (this.reverse ? 'asc' : 'desc')];
    if (this.predicate !== 'id') {
      result.push('id');
    }
    return result;
  }

  private onSuccess(data, headers) {
    this.links = this.parseLinks.parse(headers.get('link'));
    this.totalItems = headers.get('X-Total-Count');
    this.queryCount = this.totalItems;
    // this.page = pagingParams.page;
    this.events = data;
  }
  private onError(error) {
    this.jhiAlertService.error(error.message, null, null);
  }
}
```

***event-angjs.service.ts***

```js
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  Observable
} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {
  SERVER_API_URL
} from '../../app.constants';

import {
  JhiDateUtils
} from 'ng-jhipster';

import {
  EventAngjs
} from './event-angjs.model';
import {
  createRequestOption
} from '../../shared';

export type EntityResponseType = HttpResponse < EventAngjs > ;

@Injectable()
export class EventAngjsService {

  private resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/events';
  private resourceSearchUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/_search/events';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private dateUtils: JhiDateUtils) {}

  create(event: EventAngjs): Observable < EntityResponseType > {
    const copy = this.convert(event);
    return this.http.post < EventAngjs > (this.resourceUrl, copy, {
        observe: 'response'
      })
      .map((res: EntityResponseType) => this.convertResponse(res));
  }

  update(event: EventAngjs): Observable < EntityResponseType > {
    const copy = this.convert(event);
    return this.http.put < EventAngjs > (this.resourceUrl, copy, {
        observe: 'response'
      })
      .map((res: EntityResponseType) => this.convertResponse(res));
  }

  find(id: number): Observable < EntityResponseType > {
    return this.http.get < EventAngjs > (`${this.resourceUrl}/${id}`, {
        observe: 'response'
      })
      .map((res: EntityResponseType) => this.convertResponse(res));
  }

  query(req ? : any): Observable < HttpResponse < EventAngjs[] >> {
    const options = createRequestOption(req);
    return this.http.get < EventAngjs[] > (this.resourceUrl, {
        params: options,
        observe: 'response'
      })
      .map((res: HttpResponse < EventAngjs[] > ) => this.convertArrayResponse(res));
  }

  //PLACEHOLDER queryByOperation

  search(req ? : any): Observable < HttpResponse < EventAngjs[] >> {
    const options = createRequestOption(req);
    return this.http.get < EventAngjs[] > (this.resourceSearchUrl, {
        params: options,
        observe: 'response'
      })
      .map((res: HttpResponse < EventAngjs[] > ) => this.convertArrayResponse(res));
  }

  private convertResponse(res: EntityResponseType): EntityResponseType {
    const body: EventAngjs = this.convertItemFromServer(res.body);
    return res.clone({
      body
    });
  }

  private convertArrayResponse(res: HttpResponse < EventAngjs[] > ): HttpResponse < EventAngjs[] > {
    const jsonResponse: EventAngjs[] = res.body;
    const body: EventAngjs[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++) {
      body.push(this.convertItemFromServer(jsonResponse[i]));
    }
    return res.clone({
      body
    });
  }

  /**
   * Convert a returned JSON object to EventAngjs.
   */
  private convertItemFromServer(event: EventAngjs): EventAngjs {
    const copy: EventAngjs = Object.assign({}, event);
    copy.evtDate = this.dateUtils
      .convertLocalDateFromServer(event.evtDate);
    return copy;
  }

  /**
   * Convert a EventAngjs to a JSON which can be sent to the server.
   */
  private convert(event: EventAngjs): EventAngjs {
    const copy: EventAngjs = Object.assign({}, event);
    copy.evtDate = this.dateUtils
      .convertLocalDateToServer(event.evtDate);
    return copy;
  }
}
```

The two questions arising:

1. What are the missing code snippets to get the "currentOperation" method working
2. What is the right call of (change)="filter(**???**)" ?

I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should disable the last 2 drop-downs until the (valid) first drop-down value is selected.

On change of first drop-down value, pass the selected value to the back-end and based on that value send corresponding arrays of filtered values to be displayed in the both drop-downs.